# SQL Error [1248] [42000]: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: mysql

Issues : SQL Error [1248] [42000]: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tried : remove all the alias and use full path instead of alias

Original Script:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT 'OfferItm9' AS OfferNo,
       O.DocNo,
       O.Stkno,
       O.OfferPrice,
       O.StartDateItm,
       O.EndDateItm
FROM OfferItm9 O
WHERE O.EndDateItm>=CURDATE()
  AND O.Active = '1'
  AND O.UOM = 'U'
UNION SELECT 'OfferItm8' AS OfferNo,
             O.DocNo,
             O.Stkno,
             O.OfferPrice,
             O.StartDateItm,
             O.EndDateItm
FROM OfferItm8 O
WHERE O.EndDateItm>=CURDATE()
  AND O.Active = '1'
  AND O.UOM = 'U'
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery in your query above needs an alias, that is all:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 'OfferItm9' AS OfferNo, O.DocNo, O.Stkno, O.OfferPrice, O.StartDateItm, O.EndDateItm
    FROM OfferItm9 O
    WHERE O.EndDateItm >= CURDATE() AND O.Active = '1' AND O.UOM = 'U'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'OfferItm8', O.DocNo, O.Stkno, O.OfferPrice, O.StartDateItm, O.EndDateItm
    FROM OfferItm8 O
    WHERE O.EndDateItm >= CURDATE() AND O.Active = '1' AND O.UOM = 'U'
) t;
```

But, I don't even see the point of the subquery, so just use:

```sql
SELECT 'OfferItm9' AS OfferNo, O.DocNo, O.Stkno, O.OfferPrice, O.StartDateItm, O.EndDateItm
FROM OfferItm9 O
WHERE O.EndDateItm >= CURDATE() AND O.Active = '1' AND O.UOM = 'U'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'OfferItm8', O.DocNo, O.Stkno, O.OfferPrice, O.StartDateItm, O.EndDateItm
FROM OfferItm8 O
WHERE O.EndDateItm >= CURDATE() AND O.Active = '1' AND O.UOM = 'U';
```

Note: Use `UNION ALL` here for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the sub-query result with an alias.

```
SELECT * FROM 
( SELECT A, B, C, FROM TABLE
) TABLE_ALIAS
```

Where **TABLE_ALIAS** is the alias for the derived table.